# Retrieving JSON in HTML javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, struts, struts-1

I am using Struts 1.2 in my application.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1) Sending an ajax request using javascript to the action
2) Returning the JSON object as response from the action
3) Retrieving and Parsing the JSON response in javascript 
4) using the value.

I am done with the first two steps but struck with the third one (Retrieving the JSON):

**Javascript code:**

```
function getTransactionId(transactionId){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){               

         if(xhr.readyState == 4){               

            if(xhr.status == 200){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                //var p = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //alert(p);
            }
         }
        }; 
        xhr.open("POST", "returnMedia.do?transactionId=" + transactionId, true);  
        xhr.send(null); 

    }
```

**Action Code:**

```
String actualReturnDateJSON = new Gson().toJson(actualReturnDateMap);       
System.out.println(actualReturnDateJSON);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().print(actualReturnDateJSON);
```

When I print the JSON value here in console, I am getting the correct format like this: `{"02-19-2013":"02-19-2013"}`

But when I try this in javascript:

```
if(xhr.status == 200){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                //var p = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //alert(p);
            }
```

I am not getting the JSON value which got printed earlier in the console i.e. `{"02-19-2013":"02-19-2013"}`. Unfortunately, this alert statement is showing me the entire HTML file

Please let me know what is going wrong :(

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Much cleaner way to do is to use struts2-json-plugin and let the framework do the lifting for you

```
   <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
      <action name="getTransactionId" 
           class="your action class">
           <result type="json" />
      </action>
    </package>
```

and you need not meddle with response object and GSON  in your action class,the mapping will take care of it.

[Struts 2 And JSON Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately my application is running on Struts 1.2. Any possible solution for this?

Comment: It looks fine to me , can you have a look at your reponse through a Tamper Data plugin , just to be sure that the response type and other headers you set are received at the browser